# Is it possible that z-index of different CSS can work together?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm working on a piece of code where I want to show notification-dropdown over a carousel. For this purpose I'm using `z-index property`. I have two different CSS files, one for notification-dropdown and other for carousel.

I've given the higher value of z-index for notification-dropdown and lower for carousel. These values are in two different CSS files.

Is it possible that z-index property will work in this case as CSS files for notification-dropdown and carousel are different?

Comment: What made you think what “file” this was in, had _any_ relevance to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` is a property of a box in CSS 2.1 ([docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index)). It should not matter the CSS file it is specified in, as long as it targets the correct box.

In case a different index is given in more than one file, CSS ambiguity rules apply.

In order to better understand the concept, CSS make use of Stacking Contexts when rendering content. [Appendix E](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html) is a good informative article for deeper studies.